# Algorithm to Rate Objects with Numerous Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, compare

Lets say I have a list of 500 objects. I need to rate each one out of 10.

At random I select two and present them to a friend. I then ask the friend which they prefer. I then use this comparison (ie OBJECT1 is better than OBJECT2) to alter the two objects' rating out of ten.

I then repeat this random selection and comparison thousands of times with a group of friends until I have a list of 500 objects with a reliable rating out of ten.

I need to figure out an algorithm which takes the two objects current ratings, and alters them depending on which is thought to be better...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each object's rating could be (number of victories)/(number of contests entered) * 10. So the rating of the winner goes up a bit and the rating of the loser goes down a bit, according to how many contests they've previously entered.

For something more complicated and less sensitive to the luck of the draw with smaller numbers of trials, I'd suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system, but it's not out of 10. You could rescale everyone's scores so that the top score becomes 10, but then a match could affect *everyone's* rating, not just the rating of the two involved.

It all sort of depends what "reliable" means. Different friends' judgements will not be consistent with respect to each other, and possibly not even consistent over time for the same person, so there's no "real" sorted order for you to sanity-check the rankings against.

On a more abstruse point, Arrow's Impossibility Theorem states some nice properties that you'd like to have in a system that takes individual preferences and combines them to form an aggregated group preference. It then proceeds to prove that they're mutually inconsistent - you can't have them all. Any intuitive idea of a "good" overall rating runs a real risk of being unachievable.